# Reloading div content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="user_addr">

  <!--- some dynamic content here, which is being loaded from db   --->

<div class="add_address" >
    <div class="error"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="addr_id" value="0"/>
    <input type="text" id="usr_name" class="medium-input" placeholder="Enter Full Name" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="text" id="addr_line1" class="large-input" placeholder="Address Line 1" maxlength="100" />
    <input type="text" id="addr_line2" class="large-input" placeholder="Address Line 2" maxlength="100"/>
    <input type="text" id="city" class="small-input" placeholder="City Name" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="text" id="state" class="small-input" placeholder="State Name" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="text" id="pincode" class="small-input" placeholder="Pin Code" maxlength="6"/>
    <input type="text" id="phone" class="medium-input" placeholder="Mobile Number" maxlength="10"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="save_address"/>
</div>


</div>
```

I'm trying to reload/refresh `div` with id `usr_addr` whenever user click save button.

I'm using

```
 $('.save_address').click(function () {
  alert('hi');  <--- doesn't prompt in second call
  <!--- saving data to db --->
  $('#user_addr').load(location.href.replace('#', '') + ' #user_addr');// refreshing div to get latest saved data
  }
```

But, for the first time when I click `Save`, it works fine, but div gets nested and in the source code, it becomes

```
 <div id="user_addr">
     <div id="user_addr">  <--- nested after function call
        ....
        ....
      </div>
   </div>
```

And, then save button doesn't work or unable to call js function. Could anyone suggest solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to fix this :

```
$(document).on('click','.save_address',function () { // 1. use event delegation to be able to listen to .save_address element, whenever it's loaded via Ajax
  var url = location.href.replace('#', '') + '#user_addr';
  console.log(url); // just to be sure
  $.get(url, function(data){ // 2. perform an Ajax request to fetch your new content, and use a callback to handle the content
    var data = $(data).find('#user_addr').html(); // 3. find the new content in the DOM
    console.log(data);
    $('#user_addr').html(data); // 4. insert it
   });
});
```

Hope this will help :)

*NB: I wouldn't use a `input[type=submit]` as long as there is no `form` element there, but I would use a `button`*

Comment: are you missing anything in your code, it isn't working.. even I put `alert(data)` inside it, to check code flow. But, I didn't get any prompt.

Comment: in console, I got `TypeError: data.find is not a function` .

Comment: Don't you miss the callback parameter? $.get(location.href.replace('#', '') + ' #user_addr', function(data){ <<< there

Comment: I updated the code just to put some debug stuff and corrected the error you get. So you can control if the url is ok, same thing for the data you get.

Comment: It worked this time. Thanks for your help. Let me understand your code.

Comment: Yes sure, it will help others as well. :)

Comment: Well, I thought the comments in the code would be enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change `id="user_addr"` to `id="user_addr_container'` and js to

```
$('#user_addr_container').load(location.href.replace('#', '') + ' #user_addr');
```

Comment: how will it load from `location.href.replace('#', '') + ' #user_addr'` as you just asked to **change id="user_addr" to id="user_addr_container'**